# Issue on getting IMEI number on few brand devices(Huawei)

Tags: android, imei

For my app I'm getting device **IMEI** for unique value.

To get **IMEI** I have using a following code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (mTelephony.getPhoneCount() == 2) {
                // Dual sim
                IME = mTelephony.getDeviceId(0);
            } else {
                IME = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
            }
        } else {
            IME = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
        }
```

This is working good on most of the devices(may be all devices) except **Huawei** devices

For dual sim device - It'll take only first IMEI through a line

```
IME = mTelephony.getDeviceId(0);
```

But, issue is getting Second **IMEI** number sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I use this way and it works for me , give it a try

```
fun getDeviceIMEI(context: Context): String? {

try {
    val mTelephonyMgr = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission is  granted
        val imei: String? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mTelephonyMgr.imei
        } else { // older OS  versions
            mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId()
        }

        if (imei != null) {
            return imei
        }

    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}

return null
}
```

Its written in kotlin but you can get idea what I am doing, You can simplify it little more

Comment: In case of Dual Sim - will it return the IMEI of SIM1 always?

Comment: I din't test that  specifically yet . but I guess yes .

Answer (score 0):

[`getDeviceId(int slot)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId(int)) was deprecated in API level 26.

Use [`getImei()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei(int)) instead for API 26 and above.